# Flex 4 Send and load variables to a new window

Tags: forms, flex4, loadvars

I want to post some variables to a new window.

The receiving c# will then generate a CSV which will stream as a download.

In flex this used to be achieved using loadVars and specifying _blank as the target.

I currently use the following:

```
            var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            myVariables.CurrentActiveUserID = currentUserID
            myVariables.ReportRuleListID = SingleChartID

            myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            myRequest.data = myVariables;
            myLoader.load(myRequest);
```

But it does not seem to support targeting of new windows.

Any ideas.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted it with:

```
    private function sendAndLoadCSVData():void {
            var swfURL:String = this.loaderInfo.url;
            swfURL = swfURL.substr(0,swfURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            var tempDom:Array = swfURL.split("/");
            var domURL:String = tempDom.slice(0,3).join("/") + "/";
            var url:String = swfURL + "../Reporting/ExportChartCSV.aspx"

            // var post_variable:LoadVars = new LoadVars();

            var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var myVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            myVariables.CurrentActiveUserID = currentUserID
            myVariables.ReportRuleListID = SingleChartID

            myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            myRequest.data = myVariables;
            navigateToURL(myRequest, '_blank')
            //myLoader.load(myRequest);

        //  Alert.show(url);


        }
```